# Creation of Interface for json Format in TypeScript (angular)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am new to interface creation for JSON Formats. How can I create an `interface` for the following JSON in TypeScript (Angular)?

```json
{
    "football": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "club": "dfgz",
          "address": "adfs",
          "players": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "dsaf",
              "age": 4,
              "gender": ""
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "",
              "age": "",
              "gender": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to get started is to go to https://app.quicktype.io/ and type your JSON in there and what you have shown is not a full snippet, so it's hard to tell. What have you tried? What are you having difficulty with? All the existing answer are valid since you didn't explain what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
interface Sport {[sport: string]: {
    id: number, club: string, address: string, players: {
            id: number, name: string, age: number, gender: string
        }[]
    }[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface Game {
 [key: string]: SportInfo[];
}

export interface SportInfo {
   id: number;
   club: string;
   address: string;
   players: Player[];
}
export interface Player {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   age: number | string;
   gender: string;
}
```

and can be used like

```
let footballSport: Game = {
 football: [ { "id": 1, "club": "dfgz", "address": "adfs", "players": [ { "id": 1, "name": "dsaf", "age": 4, "gender": "" }, { "id": 2, "name": "", "age": "", "gender": "" } ] } ]
```

Comment: This would fail, some of the ages are strings, some are numbers.

Comment: age shouldn't be string.

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't, but from the sample JSON, it can! I'm not sure what your argument is.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
export interface Player {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: string;
  gender: string;
}
export interface FootballClub {
 id: number;
 club: string;
 address: string;
 players: Player[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface IFootballPlayer {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number | string;
  gender: string;
}

export interface IFootballClub {
  id: number;
  club: string;
  address: string;
  players: IFootballPlayer[];
}
```

then in your TypeScript you would do:

```
footballClubs: IFootballClub[] = [ { "id": 1, "club": "dfgz", "address": "adfs", "players": [ { "id": 1, "name": "dsaf", "age": 4, "gender": "" }, { "id": 2, "name": "", "age": "", "gender": "" } ] } ]
```